# Error on building docker image of Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image for a blazor WebAssembly project. Following is my **Docker** file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Sukhdari_Client.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore Sukhdari_Client.csproj
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build Sukhdari_Client.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Sukhdari_Client.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

when i try to build docker image on cmd by

```
docker build -t <projectname> .
```

i get a lot of errors [secrean shot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmz8I.png)

I am new to docker, I try various sites and documentation but I could not find any help
Any idea how can I resolve this?

contents of Sukhdari_Client.csproj are below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="wwwroot\Images\store.jpg" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Business\Business.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Common\Common.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Models\Models.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="System.Private.Xml.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="System.Data.Common.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="System.Linq.Expressions.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll" />
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.dll" />

</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: It looks like you've somehow added the Dockerfile to your project and it thinks it's a C# file. Can you edit your post and add the contents of Sukhdari_Client.csproj to it, please?

Comment: It also looks like you pasted a link to an image instead of the actual error message, so it's not clear what's gone wrong.  You shouldn't usually include screen shots of terminal windows in SO questions.

Comment: @HansKilian I have added the contents of Sukhdari_Client.csproj file at the end of question.